# How to make different font size in one textfield

Tags: flutter, textfield, textstyle

How to make different font size in one textfield?
I want to make 1 text field but so that different characters on input have different font size/color/style etc.
Expamle:

=> TextFieldForm - [ **AA** *BBaS*  OKEY MAN**!**]

Comment: The question is how do you determine which style to apply to a character?

Comment: I need the user to enter text into the TextField, but the font of the letters that he enters was different.

Comment: It's not an acceptable answer ^^ What is the scenario ? Different how ?

Comment: 1 text field. The user enters a value for example 'different' I want it to look like d = fontSize 30, i = fontSize 40, f = fontSize 50 etc.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the TextField widget. You have to build it by yourself ! Check the source code of TextField to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
RichText(
 text: TextSpan(
 text: 'Hello ',
 style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
 children: const <TextSpan>[
  TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
  ],
 ),
)
```

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Comment: I need the user to enter text into the TextField, but the font of the letters that he enters was different.

Comment: How can RichText help me?